# Is PERCENTILE() equivalent to PERCENTILE.INC() or PERCENTILE.EXC()?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

PERCENTILE() has been deprecated, so is it equivalent to PERCENTILE.INC() vs. PERCENTILE.EXC()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so is it equivalent to PERCENTILE.INC() vs. PERCENTILE.EXC()?

It's PERCENTILE.INC()`, which is the inclusive function, instead of the exclusive function.

> Returns the k-th percentile of values in a range, where k is in the range 0..1, inclusive.
>
> You can use this function to establish a threshold of acceptance. For example, you can decide to examine candidates who score above the 90th percentile.

Source: [PERCENTILE.INC()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PERCENTILE-INC-function-680F9539-45EB-410B-9A5E-C1355E5FE2ED)

This is confirmed by the fact PERCENTILE() was also the inclusive function.

> PERCENTILE(array,k)
>
> The PERCENTILE function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> - Array     Required. The array or range of data that defines relative standing.
> - K     Required. The percentile value in the range 0..1, inclusive.

Source: [PERCENTILE.INC()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PERCENTILE-function-91b43a53-543c-4708-93de-d626debdddca)

`PERCENTILE.INC()` and `PERCENTILE.EXC()` are supported by Office 2010+ and Office 365